# Exporting to text in xojo

Tags: listbox, xojo, realstudio

I want to export data from a listbox,

> ```
>   Listbox1.AddRow "001", "Orange", "1.00","Arief"
>   Listbox1.AddRow "001", "Apple", "1.00","Arief"
>   Listbox1.AddRow "001", "Banana", "1.00","Arief"
>   Listbox1.AddRow "004", "Orange", "1.00","Arief"
>   Listbox1.AddRow "005", "Apple", "1.00","Brandon"
>   Listbox1.AddRow "006", "Banana", "1.00","Brenda"
>
>   dim f as folderitem
>   dim tisx as TextOutputStream
>   f = new folderitem("item.txt")
>   tisx = f.CreateTextFile
>   dim Last_first_word as String
>   dim maxRow as Integer = Listbox1.listcount-1
>   for row as integer =  0 to maxRow
>     if Listbox1.Cell(row,0)<> Last_first_word then
>       tisx.WriteLine ""
>       tisx.writeline listBox1.cell(row,0)
>       tisx.WriteLine listBox1.cell(row,1)+" "+listBox1.cell(row,2)
>       Last_first_word=Listbox1.Cell(row,0)
>     else
>       tisx.WriteLine listBox1.cell(row,1)+" "+listBox1.cell(row,2)
>     end if
>   next
>   tisx.Close
> ```

I want to categorized all the items which is has the same code,and put the name at the last.
How to make the result like ,

> ```
>     001
>     Orange 1.00
>     Apple 1.00
>     Banana 1.00
>     Arief
>
>     004
>     Orange 1.00
>     Arief
>
>     005
>     Apple 1.00
>     Brandon
>
>     006
>     Banana 1.00
>     Brenda
> ```

Thanks

Regards,

Arief

Comment: Where does the data going into the ListBox come from? If it's an SQL database then you're better off using SQL to grab the data with `group by` and `order by`. ListBoxes should not be used as a data source.

Comment: yes, the data came from mysql database, I do creating the listbox data for the result purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to also save the name so you can display it before you move onto a new group of data. Only a minor tweak to your code was needed:

```
Listbox1.DeleteAllRows

ListBox1.AddRow("001", "Orange", "1.00", "Arief")
ListBox1.AddRow("001", "Apple", "1.00", "Arief")
ListBox1.AddRow("001", "Banana", "1.00", "Arief")
ListBox1.AddRow("004", "Orange", "1.00", "Arief")
ListBox1.AddRow("005", "Apple", "1.00", "Brandon")
ListBox1.AddRow("006", "Banana", "1.00", "Brenda")

Dim f As FolderItem
Dim tisx As TextOutputStream
f = SpecialFolder.Desktop.Child("item.txt")
tisx = f.CreateTextFile
Dim Last_first_word As String
Dim lastName As String
Dim maxRow As Integer = Listbox1.ListCount - 1
For row As Integer =  0 To maxRow
  If Listbox1.Cell(row, 0) <> Last_first_word Then
    If lastName <> "" Then tisx.WriteLine(lastName)

    tisx.WriteLine("")
    tisx.WriteLine(ListBox1.Cell(row, 0))
    tisx.WriteLine(ListBox1.Cell(row, 1) + " " + ListBox1.Cell(row, 2))
    Last_first_word = ListBox1.Cell(row, 0)
    lastName = ListBox1.Cell(row, 3)
  Else
    tisx.WriteLine(ListBox1.Cell(row, 1) + " " + ListBox1.Cell(row, 2))
  End If
Next

If lastName <> "" Then tisx.WriteLine(lastName)

tisx.Close
```

The data has to be sorted by that group number in order for this to work.